# Loop through all div with the same class and hide text with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, loops

I'm trying to loop through divs with same classes and then find an specific word at the h2 tag so i can identify it and hide or show an other div.

Here is my code:

```
    <main id="main" class="site-main home-main" role="main">

      <div class="home-product">
       <div class="image-container course-trailer">
        <a href="/"> <img src="./cine-6.jpg" class="home-image" alt=""></a>
       </div>
       <h2><a class="titleCourse" href="/">Pack 4 Cursos de Cine</a></h2>
       <div class="product-info-home">
        <div class="teacher-home" id="imparteText">Imparte </div>
        <div class="price-home">
         <span class="original-price">$2000 MXN</span>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>

      <div class="home-product">
       <div class="image-container course-trailer">
        <a href="/"> <img src="./cine-6.jpg" class="home-image" alt=""></a>
       </div>
       <h2><a class="titleCourse" href="/">Curso de guíon</a></h2>
       <div class="product-info-home">
        <div class="teacher-home" id="imparteText">Imparte </div>
        <div class="price-home">
         <span class="original-price">$1000 MXN</span>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>

      <div class="home-product">
       <div class="image-container course-trailer">
        <a href="/"> <img src="./cine-6.jpg" class="home-image" alt=""></a>
       </div>
       <h2><a class="titleCourse" href="/">Pack 4 Cursos de Cine</a></h2>
       <div class="product-info-home">
        <div class="teacher-home" id="imparteText">Imparte </div>
        <div class="price-home">
         <span class="original-price">$2000 MXN</span>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>

    </main>
```

And here is my validation for identifying the Course title and hide or show #imparteText but i don´t know how to do this in all the home-product classes:

```
      <script type='text/javascript'> 
           var title = document.getElementsByClassName('titleCourse').textContent;
           var imparte = document.getElementById('imparteText');
            if ( title.includes('Pack')){
            imparte.style.display = 'none';
            } else {
            imparte.style.display = 'block';
            }
        </script>
```

Does anybody knows how to do this? Thank you very much!

Comment: As you say in the question, you need to loop through all the DIVs. You have no loop in your code.

Comment: IDs have to be unique. You can't have multiple `id="imparteText"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop over each of the `.titleCourse` elements.

You need to change `imparteText` to a class so you can repeat it in each DIV.

To find the `imparteText` DIV in the same DIV as the `titleCourse`, use `.closest()` to find the containing DIV, then `.querySelector()` to find the DIV with that class.

```js
var courses = document.querySelectorAll('.titleCourse')

courses.forEach(course => {
  title = course.textContent;
  var imparte = course.closest(".home-product").querySelector('.imparteText');
  if (title.includes('Pack')) {
    imparte.style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    imparte.style.display = 'block';
  }
});
```

```html
<main id="main" class="site-main home-main" role="main">

  <div class="home-product">
    <div class="image-container course-trailer">
      <a href="/"> <img src="./cine-6.jpg" class="home-image" alt=""></a>
    </div>
    <h2><a class="titleCourse" href="/">Pack 4 Cursos de Cine</a></h2>
    <div class="product-info-home">
      <div class="teacher-home imparteText">Imparte </div>
      <div class="price-home">
        <span class="original-price">$2000 MXN</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="home-product">
    <div class="image-container course-trailer">
      <a href="/"> <img src="./cine-6.jpg" class="home-image" alt=""></a>
    </div>
    <h2><a class="titleCourse" href="/">Curso de guíon</a></h2>
    <div class="product-info-home">
      <div class="teacher-home imparteText">Imparte </div>
      <div class="price-home">
        <span class="original-price">$1000 MXN</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="home-product">
    <div class="image-container course-trailer">
      <a href="/"> <img src="./cine-6.jpg" class="home-image" alt=""></a>
    </div>
    <h2><a class="titleCourse" href="/">Pack 4 Cursos de Cine</a></h2>
    <div class="product-info-home">
      <div class="teacher-home imparteText">Imparte </div>
      <div class="price-home">
        <span class="original-price">$2000 MXN</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</main>
```

Comment: This worked perfect to me! I was doing it wrong and your solution for looping was very helpful. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

Part of the problem is that you've got multiple nodes with the same ID. That's not allowed; you'll need to use classes instead.

You're trying to do this all in one pass; you'll instead need to loop through each container element and check its contents individually.  Comments in the below snippet should be enough to demonstrate this approach:

```js
// iterate over product nodes:            
for (product of document.getElementsByClassName('home-product')) {
  // find the relevant nodes inside this product.  
  // We know there's only one of each in a given product, 
  // so can cheat and just use [0]:
  let title = product.getElementsByClassName('titleCourse')[0].textContent;

  // the ID can't be reused, so I'm borrowing the 
  // existing classname on the same element instead:
  let imparte = product.getElementsByClassName('teacher-home')[0]

  // we only need to hide elements, no need to explicitly 
  // 'show' since they're visible by default
  if (title.indexOf('Pack') > -1) {
    imparte.style.display = 'none'
  }
}
```

```html
<main id="main" class="site-main home-main" role="main">

  <div class="home-product">
    <div class="image-container course-trailer">
      <a href="/"> <img src="./cine-6.jpg" class="home-image" alt=""></a>
    </div>
    <h2><a class="titleCourse" href="/">Pack 4 Cursos de Cine</a></h2>
    <div class="product-info-home">
      <div class="teacher-home" id="imparteText">Imparte </div>
      <div class="price-home">
        <span class="original-price">$2000 MXN</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="home-product">
    <div class="image-container course-trailer">
      <a href="/"> <img src="./cine-6.jpg" class="home-image" alt=""></a>
    </div>
    <h2><a class="titleCourse" href="/">Curso de guíon</a></h2>
    <div class="product-info-home">
      <div class="teacher-home" id="imparteText">Imparte </div>
      <div class="price-home">
        <span class="original-price">$1000 MXN</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="home-product">
    <div class="image-container course-trailer">
      <a href="/"> <img src="./cine-6.jpg" class="home-image" alt=""></a>
    </div>
    <h2><a class="titleCourse" href="/">Pack 4 Cursos de Cine</a></h2>
    <div class="product-info-home">
      <div class="teacher-home" id="imparteText">Imparte </div>
      <div class="price-home">
        <span class="original-price">$2000 MXN</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</main>
```